# Android Device Compatibility - Stop installation

Tags: android, device

Is there a way to prevent the Android Application getting listed on a user's phone if a particular hardware is not present?

Or allow the user to install the application and perform isHardwareDetected check and show a message to the user?

For e.g. Fingerprint scanner hardware, if not available on the users phone can it be disabled via Google Play?

Also, can the Google Play Store listing be dynamically changed based on the compatibility of the device?

Regards,
Nirav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Device features**

you can prevent users from installing your app when their devices don't provide a given feature by declaring it with a  element in your app's manifest file.

For example, if your app does not make sense on a device that lacks a compass sensor, you can declare the compass sensor as required with the following manifest tag:

```
<manifest ... >
<uses-feature 
android:name="android.hardware.sensor.compass" 
android:required="true" />
...
</manifest>
```

Google Play Store compares the features your app requires to the features available on each user's device to determine whether your app is compatible with each device. If the device does not provide all the features your app requires, the user cannot install your app.

However, if your app's primary functionality does not require a device feature, you should set the required attribute to "false" and check for the device feature at runtime.

If the app feature is not available on the current device, gracefully degrade the corresponding app feature. For example, you can query whether a feature is available by calling hasSystemFeature() like this:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
if (!pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_SENSOR_COMPASS)) {
// This device does not have a compass, turn off the compass feature
disableCompassFeature();
}
```

more details [Refer Device Compatibility](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html)

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. Is there a way to display a custom message on why the app cannot be installed? I checked docs, but couldnt find a  way to display a custom message when the user cannot download app.